# function non recognized in objective-C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm new to IOS developing but this problem i'm facing does not seem logical to me. I'm declaring a function in both ViewController.h and ViewController.mm (changed to.mm because i'm using C++) but when i call it in ViewController.mm i get `use of undeclared identifier` error.

Here's the declaration in the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>

using namespace cv;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CvVideoCameraDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageview;
    CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;

}
- (UIImage *) CVMatToImage:(cv::Mat) matrice;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;

-(IBAction)cameraStart:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cameraStop:(id)sender;

@end
```

and the definition in the .mm file:

```
- (UIImage *) CVMatToImage:(cv::Mat) matrice
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:matrice.data length:matrice.elemSize()*matrice.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;

    if (matrice.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | (
                                                   matrice.elemSize() == 3? kCGImageAlphaNone : kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
                                                   );
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(
                                        matrice.cols,                 //width
                                        matrice.rows,                 //height
                                        8,                          //bits per component
                                        8 * matrice.elemSize(),       //bits per pixel
                                        matrice.step[0],              //bytesPerRow
                                        colorSpace,                 //colorspace
                                        bitmapInfo,                 // bitmap info
                                        provider,                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                       //decode
                                        false,                      //should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault   //intent
                                        );

    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return finalImage;


}
```

But when i call it inside an IBAction i get an error

```
-(IBAction)cameraStop:(id)sender
{


    [self.videoCamera stop];

    //////////////////////

    // Don't forget to process image here

    //////////////////////
    UIImage  *finalImageToOCR = CVMatToImage(cvMatrice);

    [imageview setImage:finalImageToOCR];
    G8Tesseract *tesseract = [[G8Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"fra"];
    [tesseract setImage:finalImageToOCR];
    [tesseract recognize];
    NSLog(@"%@", [tesseract recognizedText]);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[tesseract recognizedText]];


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined an *instance method* and not a *function*. Like the other method calls in your code you need to use a method call along the lines of:

```
UIImage *finalImageToOCR = [<object instance> CVMatToImage:cvMatrice];
```

Alternatively if you want a function you would declare is as:

```
UIImage *CVMatToImage(cv::Mat matrice) { ... }
```

in which case the function cannot access any instance variables.

HTH

Comment: Yes i was just writing an answer for my own question. I fixed the problem with an instance of the ViewController.
And now i've changed it to a function as you suggested and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!